# Can xml get clipboard text?

Tags: xml, variables, clipboard

I need get clipboard text in variable in xml, is there any function that connect to clipboard and use those values, is it possible to do that?

Reason why i want to do that is to help me programming faster in delphi (or c++ builder) and xml acts just template.

Here is example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<codetemplate   xmlns="http://schemas.borland.com/Delphi/2005/codetemplates"
                version="1.0.0">
    <template name="if" surround="true" invoke="auto">
        <point name="expr">
            <script language="C">
                invoke_code_completion();
            </script>
            <hint>
                conditional expression
            </hint>
            <text>
                true
            </text>
        </point>
        <description>
            if statement
        </description>
        <author>
            Embarcadero
        </author>
        <code language="C" context="methodbody"><![CDATA[if ($expr$) {
$selected$$*$$end$
}
]]>
        </code>
    </template>
</codetemplate>
```

this will produce **if (true) { }** with focus on **true**, what i need is tu use instead word true some clipboard text.

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: Are you tried the Delphi IDE [`Live Templates`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Live_Templates)?

Comment: what i was talking about above is live templates but i didn't know that they are,... finally when founded live templates definition found that they have just few built in function so my wish to implement copy inside live templates fail, ... if you know some way of how to take clipboard inside live templates, that will solve problem (i didn't find)

Answer (score 1):

XML is a data format. It can't "do" anything and doesn't have variables.

Update based on revised question:

A code template appears to be a piece of code (in some programming language) that appears as data in an XML document that includes metadata about it (presumably so that it can be stored and searched for in a code library).

The XML seems to be irrelevant to the problem. You would write code that would access the clipboard in the `<code>` element in whatever language you wanted [using the usual APIs](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=delphi%20read%20clipboard&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).

Comment: thnx for answer but take look at edit of question, i can't see what programming language is source

Comment: @tonni — err: `language="C"` suggests that programming language is C (for that particular example).

Comment: yes but C is not scripting language and whatever i put inside in code section it wouldn't work ... i will try with javascript